# Hiding sensitive data from logcat

Tags: android

[image: this is my logcat view]
am developing an android app,after compiled the apk it is showing the http url of my server in logcat!how to hide the sensitive data from logcat

`libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl:http://127.0.0.1/...` this is how it is showing the link

Comment: Do you perform Log.d or System.out.print somewhere in your code ?

Comment: If you are connecting to `http://127.0.0.1/` there is no need to hide your URL, as the server is local

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For production version use proguard and add this lines to your proguard configuration file :

```
# for remove Logging
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
  public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
  public static int v(...);
  public static int i(...);
  public static int w(...);
  public static int d(...);
  public static int e(...);
}
```

and don't forget set minifyEnabled to ture on your gradle build file (like following):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "asg.mojtaba.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

so you can use benefit of logcat on debug version and make sure you have not any log in production version.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put some check while displaying logs like

create Method for show Error logs

```
boolean isShowLog = true;

public showErrorLog(String message)
{
if(isShowLog)
Logs.e("tag", message)
}
```

and when you release your apk then make it false

There is another method to check logs

add `BuildConfig.DEBUG` before Log

Like

```
public showErrorLog(String message)
    {
    if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    Logs.e("tag", message)
    }
```

this will disable logs when your apk is in release mode, and in debug mode you can see logs.